# What is the "view_module" icon for?

Tags: android, icons, material-design

The [Material icons](https://material.io/icons/) are Google-designed, apparently with a view toward what's standard or meant to become standard, recommended by Google for use in Android apps.

In order to use them in a way that is consistent across apps and therefore intuitive for the user, I would think we would need some indication of the intended purpose or meaning of each icon. Is there a "glossary" where we can learn the intended meaning?

In particular, I'm wondering about this [`view_module`](https://material.io/icons/#ic_view_module) icon:

[image: Material view_module icon]

I have an idea of what I'd like to use it for, but I don't want to use it in a way that conflicts with some standard meaning of the icon. We had been using the "vertical 3 dots" icon, until we realized that people would think it was a menu and started tapping on it only to be frustrated.

Any idea what the `view_module` icon is supposed to be used for?

Comment: "I have an idea of what I'd like to use it for" - what command are you looking for an icon for?

Comment: @John: Not for a command, but as a symbol for what we call a "module" - a group of lessons. Modules are subordinate to "playlists" in the app.

Comment: Ah, in that case, what is the icon you're using for each individual lesson? It looks to me though that this particular icon is used in Android for arranging a list of items. Similar to how in Windows Explorer you can view items as a list, details, icons, thumbnails, etc.

Comment: @John We don't have an icon for an individual lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view module` icon is used to change the way contents are displayed on the particular Material Design oriented page. The `view module` icon displays the contents in a grid fashion, whereas its counterpart, the `view list` icon, for example on the Google Drive app (in the screenshot), displays content in the form of a list.

[image: View List mode on Google Drive]

Above is a screenshot of the `view list` view mode on the Google Drive. The icon circled in red on the top right is the `view module` icon which would switch the folder arrangement to a grid orientation as presented below, with the option to switch back to the `view list` mode.

[image: View Module mode on Google Drive]

Other than the above two, Material Design offers icons for other view modes as well depending upon their respective application. For example, `view agenda`, `view day` and `view week` for calendar oriented applications. You could visit [Material IO Icons page](http://material.io/icons) and search for the them `view` and you would be able to find all the associated icons there.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough, illustrated answer. That makes sense. I would have expected an icon for this function to be labeled `view_grid` rather than `view_module`, but clearly you're right.

Comment: @LarsH You're most welcome. And yes, I do agree `view module` is way too vague for what it does.